# systax error in awk with only sub() and print() functions

Tags: awk, gawk

I tried the following command

```
ls | awk '{ sub(/.cpp/, " ", $0); print($0); }'
```

Result

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

help me find the error

Comment: It works to me. Anyway, what do you want to do?

Comment: Works for me too. Could be shorten to: `ls | awk '{sub(/.cpp/," ")}1'`

Comment: what version of awk are you using? What's your OS?

Comment: If you are on Windows / cmd.exe, shell quoting rules do not apply. Are you?

Comment: Or, are you running on some version of Sun/Solaris. In that environment, `awk` is a **very** old version. Try using `nawk` instead. It may solve your problem immediately. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you get the error message:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
```

it means you are running old broken awk. On Solaris that's very regrettably the default /bin/awk and you should use /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead. nawk is another alternative but not as close to POSIX compliance.

Now, while your script:

```
ls | awk '{ sub(/.cpp/, " ", $0); print($0); }'
```

will execute fine with a non-broken awk, you should re-write it as:

```
ls | awk '{ sub(/.cpp/, " "); print }'
```

rather than including the default $0 arguments for those commands.

Finally - /.cpp/ is using '.' as an RE metacharacter, not a literal period character and will match `.cpp` the first time it sees it onthe line so if you had a file named `fooxcppbar.cpp` the sub() would turn it into `foo bar.cpp`. Is that what you want? If not, you might want this instead:

```
ls | awk '{ sub(/\.cpp/, " "); print }'
```

It'll still falsely match on `.cpp` earlier in the file name if present.

Comment: ls | nawk '{ sub(/.cpp/, " ", $1); print($1); }'

Comment: ls | /usr/xpg4/bin/awk '{ sub(/.cpp/, " ", $1); print($1); }'

Comment: can you tell me how to set the default awk path to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk

Comment: @Dinesh - please re-read and really think about what I said about regexps and meta-characters as using $1 is worse than using $0 when parsing file names output from ls.